# Is there a way to use Docker secrets to read from /run/secrets/redis-pass and set the redis --requirepass flag?

Tags: redis, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Is there a way to use Docker secrets to read from /run/secrets/redis-pass and set the redis --requirepass flag?

For example:

On a swarm manager set the `redis-pass`, then use `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose-prod.yml appname`

Here is the working redis service in my docker-compose.yml file.

```
  redis:
    build: ./redis
    image: redis:3.2.9
    volumes:
      - ./redis/db/:/data/
    # Without persistance
    command: sh -c "redis-server --requirepass XXXXXXXXXX"
    # With persistance (saves to /data), ref: https://redis.io/topics/persistence
    # command: sh -c "redis-server --requirepass XXXXXXXXXX --appendonly yes"
    expose:
      - "6379"
```

Here is a proposed docker-compose.yml snippet using Docker swarm stacks.

```
version: '3.1'

secrets:
    redis-pass:
        external: true

redis:
    build: ./redis
    image: redis:3.2.9
    networks:
        - frontend
    ports:
        - "6379"
    deploy:
        replicas: 2
        update_config:
            parallelism: 2
            delay: 10s
        restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
    secrets:
        - redis-pass
    environment:
        REDIS_PASS_FILE: /run/secrets/redis-pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved this by following the Docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#read-more-about-docker-secret-commands) and using entrypoint script.

Here is an approach.

## Define your Docker secret for the redis password

On your local dev machine.

Create a secrets file, ensure you add a .gitignore entry to not commit secrets to your repo.

./secrets/redis-pass.txt

`g7VacrULudmwcLnxy23JWyUNZRit7cazG2JekTCc6vccxX2LxLWoHFP8XYLbD4U9`

On your swarm leader node.

`echo "g7VacrULudmwcLnxy23JWyUNZRit7cazG2JekTCc6vccxX2LxLWoHFP8XYLbD4U9" | docker secret create redis-pass -`

## Create a redis config file

./redis/redis.conf

Define the requirepass property.

`requirepass XXXXXXXXXX`

## Update redis Dockerfile

Copy the config into the container at build time.

./redis/Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.6

# add our user and group first to make sure their IDs get assigned consistently, regardless of whatever dependencies get added
RUN addgroup -S redis && adduser -S -G redis redis

# grab su-exec for easy step-down from root
RUN apk add --no-cache 'su-exec>=0.2'

ENV REDIS_VERSION 3.2.9
ENV REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.2.9.tar.gz
ENV REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA 6eaacfa983b287e440d0839ead20c2231749d5d6b78bbe0e0ffa3a890c59ff26

# for redis-sentinel see: http://redis.io/topics/sentinel
RUN set -ex; \
    \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        coreutils \
        gcc \
        linux-headers \
        make \
        musl-dev \
    ; \
    \
    wget -O redis.tar.gz "$REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL"; \
    echo "$REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA *redis.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c -; \
    mkdir -p /usr/src/redis; \
    tar -xzf redis.tar.gz -C /usr/src/redis --strip-components=1; \
    rm redis.tar.gz; \
    \
# Disable Redis protected mode [1] as it is unnecessary in context
# of Docker. Ports are not automatically exposed when running inside
# Docker, but rather explicitely by specifying -p / -P.
# [1] https://github.com/antirez/redis/commit/edd4d555df57dc84265fdfb4ef59a4678832f6da
    grep -q '^#define CONFIG_DEFAULT_PROTECTED_MODE 1$' /usr/src/redis/src/server.h; \
    sed -ri 's!^(#define CONFIG_DEFAULT_PROTECTED_MODE) 1$!\1 0!' /usr/src/redis/src/server.h; \
    grep -q '^#define CONFIG_DEFAULT_PROTECTED_MODE 0$' /usr/src/redis/src/server.h; \
# for future reference, we modify this directly in the source instead of just supplying a default configuration flag because apparently "if you specify any argument to redis-server, [it assumes] you are going to specify everything"
# see also https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/4#issuecomment-50780840
# (more exactly, this makes sure the default behavior of "save on SIGTERM" stays functional by default)
    \
    make -C /usr/src/redis -j "$(nproc)"; \
    make -C /usr/src/redis install; \
    \
    rm -r /usr/src/redis; \
    \
    apk del .build-deps

RUN mkdir /data && chown redis:redis /data
VOLUME /data
WORKDIR /data

COPY redis.conf /home/redis/
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# EXPOSE 6379
# CMD ["redis-server"]
```

## Update docker-entrypoint.sh with a sed command.

./redis/docker-entrypoint.sh

***The sed command will replace value of requirepass property in the redis.conf file with password from the redis-pass secret from /run/secrets/redis-pass.***

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Updated password using sed
sed -i "s/requirepass XXXXXXXXXX/requirepass `cat /run/secrets/redis_password`/" /home/redis/redis.conf

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
# or first arg is `something.conf`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ] || [ "${1%.conf}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- redis-server "$@"
fi

# allow the container to be started with `--user`
if [ "$1" = 'redis-server' -a "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
    chown -R redis .
    exec su-exec redis "$0" "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

## Update your docker-compose.yml file

./docker-compose.yml

Define compose version of 3.1

```
version: "3.1"
```

Define secrets

```
secrets:
  redis-pass:
    # local dev machine
    #file: ./secrets/redis-pass.txt
    # production environment
    external: true
```

Define redis service.

```
  redis:
    build: ./redis
    image: redis:3.2.9
    command: sh -c 'redis-server /home/redis/redis.conf'
    expose:
      - "6379"
    # networks:
    #   - frontend
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    secrets:
      - redis-pass
    tty: true
```

## Validate requirepass was updated

```
➜  blah git:(master) ✗ docker-compose exec redis sh
/data # ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 sh -c redis-server /home/redis/redis.conf
   10 root       0:03 redis-server /home/redis/redis.conf
   28 root       0:00 sh
   34 root       0:00 ps -ef
/data # cat /home/redis/redis.conf
requirepass g7VacrULudmwcLnxy23JWyUNZRit7cazG2JekTCc6vccxX2LxLWoHFP8XYLbD4U9
/data #
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 8):

You can do it this way

```
services:   redis:
    image: redis
    secrets:
      - redis_pass
    environment:
        REDIS_PASS_FILE: /run/secrets/redis_pass
    command: [
      "bash", "-c",
      '
       docker-entrypoint.sh
       --requirepass "$$(cat $$REDIS_PASS_FILE)"
      '
    ]
```

like suggested here:

- https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/46#issuecomment-335326234
- https://github.com/docker-library/redis/issues/46#issuecomment-364761650

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other option to achieve that:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.1
    command: bash -c 'redis-server --requirepass "$$(cat /run/secrets/redis_password)"'
```

Note this option doesn't use environment variables (they may leak between containers)

Answer (score 0):

Updated @chrisrewin's answer for 2023:

In recent versions (>=6), @chrisrewin's Dockerfile instructions are included in the base image.

There is a fairly simple and flexible way to handle this scenario: use `envsubst` over files in a templates directory. This way, you do not have to hardcode the configuration file; you can use whatever configuration file you want and whatever docker command you want.

##### Step 1: Create a Dockerfile

```
FROM redis:<version-of-choice>

RUN apk -U add bash gettext && \
    mkdir -p /etc/redis/conf && chmod -R 755 /etc/redis && \
    mkdir -p /var/log/redis && chown -R redis:redis /var/log/redis # <-- if you want to log here.

COPY templates /etc/redis/templates
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

# optional
COPY redis.conf.default /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD ["redis-server","/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
```

##### Step 2: Create an entrypoint

Copy the entrypoint from your version of redis:

```
$ docker run --rm -it redis:<version-of-choice> cat /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh > entrypoint.sh
```

and add this to the top (Note the shebang line should be bash):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if ! [[ -v "REDIS_PASSWORD" ]]; then
    export REDIS_PASSWORD=$(cat "$REDIS_PASSWORD_FILE")
fi

if ! [[ -f /etc/redis/conf/conf.lock ]]; then
    ( cd /etc/redis; find templates -type f -name '*.template' -exec bash -c 'cat "$1" | envsubst | install -m 755 -D /dev/stdin "conf/$(basename "${1%.template}")"' _ {} \; ); 
    touch /etc/redis/conf/conf.lock
fi
```

##### Step 3: Create a config template

In a templates directory in your project root, use all the environment variables you want:

```
# templates/redis.conf.template
requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
logfile "${REDIS_LOGFILE}"
```

The entrypoint will set `REDIS_PASSWORD` to your secret if you set `REDIS_PASSWORD_FILE` instead:

```yaml
services:
  redis:
    image: <your-built-image>
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/redis_password
    secrets:
      - redis_password
    command: ['redis-server','/etc/redis/conf/redis.conf']

secrets:
  redis_password:
    external: true
```

##### Advantages

Now you can do pretty much whatever you want:

- pick one of multiple configs
- mount a `templates/` directory
- mount a static config
- use whatever docker command you want
- still pass `--requirepass`
- mount a local log directory
- run as a specified user

> Note on custom user: with this configuration, you must mount something to `/etc/redis` with proper permissions. If you're not mounting a directory for testing purposes, then I recommend running this as root. The files in `/etc` should be owned by root anyway. If you wanted a completely custom user baked-in to the image, then you have to change the Dockerfile and entrypoint.